Schema changes made to 'ab_user' table of Superset version 3.0.1 is not reflected in DB
Currently I am using Apache Superset version 3.0.1
I want to make schema changes in the ab_user table of superset.
In the config file I made the necessary changes. But this schema change is not applied to the DB.
When I run superset, it throws the error the said 'custom column' doesn't exist in DB.
I tried 'superset db upgrade' and 'superset init' commands. But still the changes aren't reflected in DB. Is there any flags or other commands that needs to be run so that the schema changes reflect in DB.
The code used is attached below.
from flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.models import User
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    String
)
class CustomUser(User):
     __tablename__ = "ab_user"
     time_zone = Column(String(64))

This adds time_zone to the schema for ab_user. But this column doesn't get added to DB.
I also created custom Security Manger to override the user model.
from flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager import SecurityManager
from .sec_models import CustomUser
from .sec_views import MyUserDBModelView

class MySecurityManager(SecurityManager):
    user_model = CustomUser

I was expecting the schema change to be automatically applied to the ab_user table in superset database. I tried 'superset db upgrade' and 'superset init' commands. But still the changes aren't reflected in DB.
